# Not-So-Simple Substitution Cipher?

Tags: cryptanalysis, substitution-cipher

The first go-to weakness when talking about substitution ciphers is frequency analysis. It assumes that there's a simple 1 to 1 character mapping between the plain text and the cipher text.

Could a frequency analysis be thwarted if this were a 1 to Many mapping?

For example, what if the input text contained say 30 characters: 26 letters, space, period, question mark, and exclamation mark. Enough for most communication needs between two people. The output could be quite a bit larger, like the 95 printable characters. `E` could be mapped to multiple output characters that appear at unusual frequencies in the cipher text that don't look like `E` on a frequency analysis. This mapping could also map `space` to 1 or more characters so you can't analyze word length or word frequency.

Every character could map to at least 3 output characters and knowing that some characters are already pretty rare they may not even need to be mapped to that many. Perhaps just 2 or even 1 that way other more frequently used characters could map to 5 or 6 cipher text characters.

Is there a different kind of analysis that could target a cipher like this?

Answer (score 5):

This is called homophonic encryption, and has been around for a long time.

In terms of cryptanalysis of such ciphers, there is a nice thesis from SJSU on this topic which is available [here](http://scholarworks.sjsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1195&context=etd_projects). The attacks tested in that cipher were based on hill climbing and local optimization techniques. The conclusion states:

> We designed and implemented an efficient attack on the homophonic substitution ciphers.
>   The attack is based on the hill-climbing heuristic technique. The proposed algorithm has
>   a multi-layered architecture with three nested loops to solve the challenges imposed by
>   the homophonic substitution ciphers and the hill-climbing technique. The algorithm was
>   successfully tested on simple substitution ciphers and many instances of homophonic
>   substitution ciphers with variable ciphertext sizes and cipher symbol sizes. [..] For the ciphertexts having minimum 3000 characters and
>   maximum 75 cipher symbols, the algorithm was able to break at least 85% of cipher
>   symbols.

So, homophonic substitution increases the required ciphertext length, as expected, for a high rate of success of correctly decrypting plaintext characters. If 55 ciphertext symbols are used (to flatten the frequency distribution) the success rate increases from about 10% for a ciphertext length of 300 characters to about 80% for a ciphertext length of 4000 characters.

If 95 ciphertext characters are used, at 4000 character ciphertext length, the success rate is around 50%.

Comment: It’s not clear to me how this answers the question *`Is there a different kind of analysis that could target a cipher like this?`* It would be cool if you could expand your answer accordingly… after all – Corey is asking about *“analysis”* (read: other options of cryptanalysis besides frequency analysis to target such ciphers). He did not ask *“can you identify what kind of encryption this is”*.